# Upload image to database: Cannot convert value of type

Tags: spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I'm trying to store images in my database but I got this error. Where am I wrong?

JSP

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post"
    modelAttribute="bookForm" action="${bookActionUrl}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <spring:bind path="image">
        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><th><spring:message
                        code="label.image" /></th></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <form:label for="image" path="image">Image</form:label>
                <form:input path="image" type="file" />
                <form:errors path="image" class="control-label" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>
</form:form>
```

Controller

```
public String saveBook(@ModelAttribute("bookForm") @Validated Book book, BindingResult result, Model model, @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] image,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {

    for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : image) {
        System.out.println("Saving file: " + aFile.getOriginalFilename());
        book.setImage_name(aFile.getOriginalFilename());
        book.setImage(aFile.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Added");
    }

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("genreList", populateDefaultModel(model));
        return "booksView/bookform";
    } else {

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");
        if (book.isNew()) {
            // System.out.println(book.getId());
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "book added successfully!");
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "book updated successfully!");
        }
        bookService.saveOrUpdate(book);
        // POST/REDIRECT/GET
        return "redirect:/motsach/"; // + book.getId();
    }
}
```

multipartResolver

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver getCommonsMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520); // 20MB
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);  // 1MB
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

DAO Implements

```
public void save(Book book) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    String sql = "INSERT INTO Books(TENSACH, TACGIA, NHANXET, TINHTRANG, THELOAI, IMAGE, IMAGE_NAME) "
            + "VALUES ( :tensach, :tacgia, :nhanxet, :tinhtrang, :theloai, :image, :image_name)";

    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, getSqlParameterByModel(book), keyHolder);
    book.setId(keyHolder.getKey().intValue());
}
```

Model

```
Integer book_ID;
String tensach;
String tacgia;
String nhanxet;
String tinhtrang;
List<String> theloai;
byte[] image;
String image_name;
String data;
```

The error:

> Failed to convert property value of type org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile to required type byte[] for property image; 
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
>   Cannot convert value of type org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile to required type byte for property image[0]: PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile`

Comment: you have `CommonsMultipartFile[]` as parameter. There is only one file right? Try removing the `[]`.

Comment: I agree with Jack Flamp's diagnosis ..if that doesn't come out to be reason, its likely JSP code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I've figured it out. Everything's fine, but those checking code cause the error. I just need to delete them and done!

```
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    model.addAttribute("genreList", populateDefaultModel(model));
    return "booksView/bookform";
} else {
```